# Preprocessor directive not working in for loop

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to know how preprocessor directives are evaluated, when they are placed in a loop in **C**/C++? 
Following is the code, which uses directive in a for loop, but it doesn't work. Why is it so?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Student
{
public:
    int roll;
    int marks;

    Student()
    {
        roll = 10;
        marks = 0;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int iCounter;

    char attr[][6] = {"roll", "marks"};

    Student std;

#define PRINT1(std, X) printf("%d", std.##X);
    for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 2; iCounter++)
    {
        PRINT1(std, attr[iCounter])
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it? `attr` is no member of class `Student`.

Comment: _[devil's advocate for Q&A quality purposes, because in reality I can guess what you mean here]_ How are we supposed to know your definition of "working" by only reading code that, by your own admission, _does not exhibit a valid implementation of that definition_? And why is this tagged C?

Comment: I think you need to [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and understand how C++ and the preprocessor work, because this is not at all valid code.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem. Please tell us what behavior you experience (compile/runtime error?). Also: please do not use `std` as a variable name, because this is also a standard namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor is a pre-compilation phase. It is essentially a code generator and, as such, has no knowledge of or interaction with your `for` loops.

You simply cannot iterate over a class's members in this manner.

Here's what your preprocessed code looks like (I've omitted header expansions for obvious reasons):

```
class Student
{
public:
    int roll;
    int marks;

    Student()
    {
        roll = 10;
        marks = 0;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int iCounter;

    char attr[][6] = {"roll", "marks"};

    Student std;

    for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 2; iCounter++)
    {
        printf("%d", std.attr[iCounter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As `attr` is not a member of `std` (terrible name for an object; please change it), hopefully you can now see how this is not going to "work" as you intend.

Furthermore, [your macro is actually inherently broken and produces an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b387ac713cc74a1), because you are using `##` where you shouldn't. Even if this code were what you wanted, the proper definition would be simply:

```
#define PRINT1(std, X) printf("%d", std.X);
```

Comment: when "##" can be used ?

Comment: @user2393267 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation It's used to concatenate two tokens into one token (e.g. `ch ## ar` -> `char`). You're not trying to concatenate anything; just putting two tokens next to each other is not concatenation.